# Ubuntu bash Small Script Help

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to run the following bash script, but it does not display anything on the terminal window and i get no errors either. I am trying to display the currentid value to be shown on the terminal screen as the output while using the builtin function when I run it through the command line.

```
#! /bin/bash

currentid()
{
return 608

echo builtin currentid "$@"

}

currentid
```

Comment: Place echo statements at various points to see what is happening. Do you think anything in `currentid` will execute after `return`?

Comment: @JoeP Better to run it with `bash -x` then clutter it up with `echo`s

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are trying to get the `pid` of your script and use it as variable later on? If so, here are some tips:

1. You don't need the `builtin` command as `currentid` is not a `builtin` as far as I know. You can see what `builtin` does like so:

   ```
   $ help builtin
   builtin: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
   Execute shell builtins.

   Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
   lookup.  This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
   as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.

   Exit Status:
   Returns the exit status of SHELL-BUILTIN, or false if SHELL-BUILTIN is
   not a shell builtin..
   ```

   You can find a list of all the builtins with `compgen -b`.
2. I am going to take a leap of faith here and guess that with `currentid` you are trying to get the `pid` or Process Id of the script. Please correct me if `currentid` refers to something else.

   To get the current `pid` of your script, you can use `$$` or `$BASHPID`. You can learn more about the differences in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables). I am not sure why you are hard-coding a return of 608, but if you want to change the `pid` of your script to that, please clarify your question.

   With that in mind, your script would look like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   printf "%s" "$$"
   ```

   Which prints your current `pid` safely. But do keep in mind that you can call `$$` or `$BASHPID` in your script later on for whatever you want.

Some more general tips:

- Here is a [great answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) from our sister site about why to use `prinf` over `echo`
- The [Bash Reference Guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Introduction) is amazing for laying out every option available.
- [Greg's Bash Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) has some great example of real-world code and best practice.

Good Luck!